# How to properly structure jobs that only call methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-structure

I have several after_create methods (mostly to deliver emails or messages on the platform) and they call jobs which eventually call methods, but my code is starting to be structured like this which doesn’t really look nice

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  after_create: :deliver_message_job

  def deliver_message_job
    DeliverMessageJob.perform_later self.id
  end

  def deliver_message
    # logic to deliver message
  end
end
```

and in the job, I just call the method

```
class DeliverMessageJob < ApplicationJob
 queue_as :default

 def perform(message_id)
  Message.find(message_id).deliver_message
 end
end
```

Is there a better way to go about structuring this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue using the callback, then you can pass a block that does what the `Message#deliver_message_job` method is doing for you so that you don't need to write out that method since it offers you little but a handle for the callback.

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  after_create { |msg| DeliverMessageJob.perform_later(msg.id) }

  # . . .
end
```

If you want to get rid of the `Message#deliver_message` method, then maybe you could put the logic for delivering the message into `DeliverMessageJob#perform` instead.  This may make more sense semantically since it's purpose is clearly just to deliver a message.

```
class DeliverMessageJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message_id)
    message = Message.find(message_id)
    # Copy over/refactor the Message#deliver_message logic.
    # Do some stuff with the message to deliver it . . .
  end
end
```

It is worth asking yourself "Should a message know how to deliver itself?" The answer is probably either "No, it shouldn't" or "It's not important", in which case just let `DeliverMessageJob` worry about the details.  This way, you have removed a couple of methods from the `Message` model and slimmed it out a bit, and made your classes neater and simpler.